# Merge two numpy record arrays by element

Tags: python, numpy

I'd like to create single `numpy` structured array from two arrays, which both have a key and count. The first array is a subset of the second, and I'd like to add the count from the second to the first, by matching the "key" element in both arrays in the most efficient manner.

```py
import numpy as np

subset = np.array([(3, 2), (7, 3), (4, 2)],
                  dtype=[('key', '<i8'), ('count', '<i8')])
total = np.array([(9, 50), (3, 12), (4, 60), (7, 19)],
                 dtype=[('key', '<i8'), ('count', '<i8')])
```

The preferred end result would be

```py
np.array([(3, 2, 12), (7, 3, 19), (4, 2, 60)],
         dtype=[('key', '<i8'), ('subset_count', '<i8'), ('total_count', '<i8')])
```

How would I go about to do this?

Comment: `recfunctions` might have something that does this.  But most of those functions, make a new array with a new dtype, and fill it by field from the source arrays.  Or this might suit pandas better.

Comment: Thanks, just noticed that `numpy.lib.recfunctions.join_by('key', subset, total, jointype='inner', r1postfix='_subset', r2postfix='_total', usemask=False)` will do the trick!